# What are the factors that rev hang depend on? Does rev hand depend on the engine load?

Tags: electronic-control-module, emissions, fuel-injection, throttle-body, air-fuel-ratio

I know that rev hangs are intentionally introduced to modern vehicles that operate on electronic throttle bodies, by programming the ecu to close the throttle valve slowly (in gasoline engines) even when you let go off the accelerator pedal quickly ,so that you can reduce emissions.

I have read that when you close the throttle valve quickly it takes some time for the fuel injectors to cut off the fuel supply making the air-fuel mixture available in the engine to be richer thus causing higher hydrocarbon emissions. So my question is "Will letting go off accelerator at high engine load conditions (say you are flooring it and letting it go completely) will increase the duration of rev hang?".

My logic behind this is that fuel injector will be supplying more fuel at higher loads and hence letting go accelerator at higher load will result in more amount of fuel injected before it responds and cuts off fuel. To burn of this extra fuel completely then you would require more air and hence increased duration over which the throttle valve has to be kept open by the ecu (i.e rev hang). Also in port fuel injected vehicles there will be some fuel that wets a portion of intake runner and this fuel that wets the runners cause more rev-hang in port fuel injected vehicle.

Here is the video explaining rev hang: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mm6SSeLivqE

Also a counter argument to this could be that the throttle valve will be opened more at higher loads so the ecu doesn't need to maintain/keep the throttle valve open for an even larger duration to burn the excess fuel injected.

Here is video that seems to show that you have more rev hang at higher load: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INtfe3xJXF8

Also what are all the factors that can affect rev hang?

Comment: I'm not clear that this is related to "Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair but rather design and/or theory of fuel injection systems.

Comment: @jwh20 A lot of the questions in this site seems to be theory stuffs. But if you would suggest a better alternate site for asking the question it would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: How about https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jwh20 I thought about it too but as it turns out engineering is not limited to just automobile engineering alone. There are a lot of branches in engineering and i hope you know that. And i felt this the place that should/would be having more number of people focussed on automobile knowledge than a general site for engineering. Or the least this site has more similar questions like the one i just posted. If you still feel like this question has nothing to do with this site then I have nothing more to prove my point.

Comment: @AbhishekPG well, some of us are apprentice trained and then went on to do a degree in engineering... so I agree that your question is more than maintenance and repair - programming, combustion theory are all part of what needs to be considered.

Comment: I would disagree with closing, as this is about engine theory and how they run. We aren't repairing, no, but we are gaining an understanding of how an engine operates. Not outside the realm of the site, and therefore should not be off-topic.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 so do you think using a faster cpu in the ecu would improve the situation and how could that be done?

Comment: @AbhishekPG - You can close your own question, however, you're not going to get much of a response elsewhere in another stack. In other stacks it will be closed as off-topic because it's about cars, even though it's peripherally about cars.

Comment: I'll do some research on this ... I've been doing some tuning studies as of late. In the videos I was watching, it actually showed a way to overcome this in some way. I'll need to rewatch the videos to see where to make the changes. I believe there is a table in most newer ECUs which handles this so you don't have the lag as well as it helps take care of the excess fuel on quick deceleration and fuel enrichment on quick acceleration.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I don't know anything about ecu tuning but I had read that it can be done by modifying throttle control codes or something like that. Also I had heard somewhere that the ecu will prevent the burning off the excess mixture if you apply brakes. Probably the ecu will detect it as an emergency and will stop the engine from burning the remaining fuel so that additional power isn't generated which could reduce the amount of braking required and the stopping distance. I am not really sure if it's a thing or if it was just me imagining it.

Comment: @AbhishekPG Get the 'rev-hang' tuned out of your ECU, easy done. Then, you can add a lighter flywheel if it suits your driving style.